# Visual Studio 2012 for windows 8 not showing win32 console application option

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I downloaded Microsoft visual studio 2012 for windows 8 to run C++ programs but when I go to New Project -> Templates -> Visual C++ it doesn't show option for win32 console application instead its showing App XAML files .What can be the solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably downloaded the version which allows only the development of Windows 8 apps.If you are not interested in doing so you should download the Express for Desktop version.

Comment: I am not interested in development of windows 8 apps so should I uninstall it and re install desktop version ?

Comment: Yes, you can get it from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673